# Using "Execute JavaScript Code" action in Azure Logic App: error about integration account being required

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to run custom JavaScript in logic App using an (Execute JavaScript Code) action, but I am getting this error:

> Failed to save logic app httpResponses. The workflow must be associated with an integration account to use the workflow run action 'Execute_JavaScript_Code' of type 'JavaScriptCode'.

How can you actually do this?

Comment: please mark the answer below as correct if you are satisfied

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To run the inline code action you need an integration account. These have some different pricing tiers. You only need to create it and then on the Logic App Workflow settings associate it. See below:

[image: configure integration account]

[image: Select integration account]

Comment: How could I run Jquery Code ?

Comment: why not use the built in js functions to work with html getelementbyid getelementbyclass?

Comment: I am developing logic app in Visual Studio - what should I do to go to workflow settings ?